# ASPX No redirecciona a donde debe

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo esta parte del código cuando se hace una acción `Response.Redirect("FPMV106.aspx")`

pero no me redirecciona ahí, me redirecciona a una pagina del proyecto "Inicio.apsx".

También intenté con `Server.Transfer("FPMV106.aspx")` y no lo hace a fuerzas tengo que introducir la pagina en la barra de dirección

Ya le busqué y no le encuentro por donde!

Alguien que me pueda ayudar

Comment: SuperYo, tu pregunta se reporto como de baja calidad, te sugiero leer [ask] que te brinda información para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtenga buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te anda este **Response**:

```
Response.Redirect("index.aspx", true);
```

Proba lo siguente:

Anda a la parte de *diseño* en tu visual studio y busca el boton que deberia hacer el *redirect*. Anda sus propiedades, presionando f4, busca su propiedad **PostBackUrl** y ahi escribi la URL de tu pagina a redireccionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias es exactamente lo que buscaba

Comment: Si te sirvio mi ayuda, dale el voto.Saludos SuperYo